# Azure, multiple services with single DNS endpoint

Tags: web-services, azure, dns

So we are migrating to Azure from a traditional IIS hosted environment.

The situation with our current solution is that there are three web services hosted in IIS under one single site. The services are all accessible via http://api.example.com/ServiceName.svc

For backward compatibility we need the same availability from Azure, Cloud Web Services. If the services are deployed as separates then they have different DNS names. And if they are bundled together then they must operate on different ports. That is my understanding anyway, meaning we are snookered.

Is it possible to get around this at all?

One solution I had was to create a very light proxy/router service that accepted requests for the three services and then routed to the appropriate internal service based on the full URL and not just the host.

I'm very new to Azure so perhaps there is something under the bonnet that can help with all  of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your services are all under a single project, you should have no issue deploying them to a single cloud service (and thus, a single host name/port).

Comment: Each service is an separate C# project

Comment: So how do you currently deploy them to IIS? Just pick the same deployment folder?

Comment: There are different folders within the same website.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of a.) your project layout and b.) your IIS website folder layout? I think I'm missing something in how you get from a to b.